# Allow the text paragraphs to fall under a right-hand side box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help in HTML and CSS coding. I want something like the below

[image]

The last paragraph i.e the one on the left-hand side of the red box has the following styling :

```
float:left; margin-right:60px; width:400px;
```

and the box on the right has

```
height: 219px; float: left; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-top: 4px; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); width: 184px;
```

For now it looks fine. But if the content of the last paragraph increases then it should accordingly fall below the red box, but it remains fixed on the left hand side with the fixed width. It does not take the full page width.

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Neha

Comment: instead of floating last para to left... float the red box to right

Comment: But then the red box falls below the paragraph and if I remove the width of the paragraph then it takes the full width of the page and the red box falls below it.

Comment: kindly check following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9Lc2w9rq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must justify the text in the paragraph.

`text-align: justify;`

http://jsfiddle.net/qgv1ja5p/

Comment: text-align: justify is not popular web standard anymore